# Fighting techniques in an arena of rings rotating in alternating directions

Tags: civilization, combat, fight

This might be a bit story based, but here goes-

I have an idea for an arena for one of my civilizations which involves about 20 rings a yard wide and rotating each other at different speeds. the outer rings rotate slower so you don't get thrown to the wall as easily, and the wall itself rotates along with the outermost ring as well. each rings rotates at a random speed(not too fast or slow so that the centrifugal force throws you out, just enough to make you unsteady when changing rings). the only stationary ground is the center circle a yard wide. Each ring is a different base height than the ones next to it by at least four inches, enough to make you stumble. Apart from the base height, it gradually goes up about a foot(the amount of times it does this depends on which ring it is. closer rings do it less), which adds to the tripping hazards. when the arena starts, the fighters are start along the edge of the rings, which begin stopped, and quickly speed up over the course of thirty seconds. elimination is decided depending on the mode, which can include death, hitting the ground, or being tagged.

so my question is this- what fighting techniques would someone use on this rotating arena for each game mode? the only weapons that start on the field are(if allowed) swords, shields, spears, and rarely bow and arrow. most times it is unarmed combat.

Comment: What kind of society? It seems that killing or maiming would be rare. It would be boring if everyone is only stumbling around and falling flat. So you need people who get good at the stepping, but alsohave skill in hand to hand or armed combat. This represents a huge investment per person. You don't want to get them killed. Comparably, gladiators rarely fought to death and death was more often for lesser armed/weak prisoners. The unwanted.

Comment: Only a yard wide? I doubt there'd be any unique fighting styles because they'd have to rotate so slowly to permit any kind of balance that you might as well be fighting on the deck of a boat. It's the sharpness of the arc. If, for example, one ring rotates once per 10 seconds (6 RPM) you're perpendicular to your opponent in 2.5 seconds - if you could keep your balance or keep your ankle/knee/hip from being twisted or wrenched. And a single yard isn't enough space to walk (or hop, in this case) to try to keep facing your opponent. Exactly how fast is the slowest and fastest rotations (RPM)?

Comment: BTW, I get the fact that a highly acrobatic fighter would be "dancing" around on these plates... but at anything but really slow speeds (like 0.001 RPM) they'd be spending so much time in the air that they'd have little time to actually fight. They'd be spending all their concentration figuring out where they're going to land and what would happen in the next split-second after that.

Comment: How many fighters are we talking about in the ring at once?

Comment: @Daron, between 2 and 24, most of the time around twelve.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b Are large teams or free-for-all more common?

Comment: @Daron mostly ffa, but teams are sometimes used.

Comment: i dont think there will be much change as long you have good stance and good foot work ( im not recommend jumping though, especially against weapon), im not good with math but taking JBH comment regarding the speed, sound like it wont turn your body to forcefully, though blade weapon probably bad idea for this, since i imagine it may can affect the edge alignment, but it probably better for unarmed combat even help for increasing the impact force using the rotation, i remember something similar like this in some kung fu movie before too. and regarding the stance they can use crane stance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Go to the Centre.**

Boring answer. But the easiest place to fight from is the centre since it doesn't move. Here are some complications that prevent the whole game being a race to the centre:

**Complication (1)** There are weapons scattered across the arena. When the match begins each player must quickly decide which weapon they want, compare to the distance from the centre, and make a decision. It is a trade-off mind-game between weapon choice and positioning.

**Complication (2)** Some fighters prefer to not have the centre. Standing on the innermost ring means they can orbit the fighter on the centre. They train to take advantage of how the other fighter must constantly rotate. This is an extra advantage if you rotate towards your opponent's weapon side rather than shield side.

**Complication (3)** Sometimes the rotation directions swap and the advantage flips around.

**Complication (4)** Being on a lower level than your opponent gives you an advantage. See diagram.

[image]

If you are low down enough you can hit your opponents feet but they cannot hit you at all.

**Complication (5)** Long weapons: A longer weapon allows you to threaten more adjacent rings. In normal circumstances when fighting a spear you want to close with them as quickly as possible. But in the arena this means you need to cross several rings quickly which is dangerous.

**Complication (2+5)** If you favour the centre you invariably need to use a long weapon. If you don't your opponent can take as much time as they want to find a long weapon and then simply outrange you.

Considering all of the above, the exact layout of long weapons will have a huge impact in the game. I would imagine the audience will make bets based on (a) history of the fighters preferring the centre or outside and (b) the starting weapon layout before the fighters enter.

**Bonus:** In order to prevent camping and inertia one option is to have a time limit, or to add extra weapons near the edge of the arena as time goes on. Adding ranged weapons in particular would make the game much more dynamic.

**Note:** When I wrote this I assumed there would only be two fighters.  Things are probably different if there are six or seven, at leastt in a free-for-all. The centre is still the easiest place to fight from, but not if there are six others trying to knock you off.

Comment: What if no-one moves towards the centre if someone else has it? And the height difference can be advantageous for the higher people. Horse riders are seen as superior. I've always assumed it's because they can hit full force downwards towards faces and possibly torso, while others can't strike as easily towards the head.

Comment: @Trioxidane I believe horses are only considered better if they can keep moving. Being on top of the horse wouldn't help you hit harder except from the movement of the horse.

Comment: @Trioxidane You know I assumed there were only two fighters. I don't know how this changes if there are six or seven. The centre is still the easiest place to fight from, but not if there are six others trying to knock you off.

Answer (score 2):

Fighting will be rather the same unless on high level I imagine.

If you jump from one platform to another, you're taking an awful risk. You use time to jump and balance out, making you an easy target. If you fall, you can automatically lose in one of the games, or be dragged to your opponent on a different ring, or at best just lay down on the same ring and quickly get to your feet.

Fighting will likely take place on the same rings. It gives an equal footing (pun lucky coincidence), the speeds are known and of the least concern. The starting outside ring also has the most room to comfortably move. If one is left handed and the other right handed they might be on adjacent rings, but clashing once in a while makes any advantage you might get with a swing vanish after. So you need to win a swing, or go to the same ring with all tbe risks involved. Besides, being lower that your target might prove a disadvantage, unless you're ducking and only go for feet.

Staffs and spears would be the weapon of choice. Besides it already being a great weapon, often winning of swords and such, you can use the momentum as well to unbalance or harm your opponent. First strike can mean a lot, but it would be a form of jousting in the end.

Tag is the one that makes most sense. Here jumping from ring to ring can make a great difference, getting closer with the right ring, or further away with another. Problem is, whatever you do, you'll be in an advantage as the tagger. The other needs to take risk, or just run away on the same ring. If the tagger goes to a middle ring, they can always force getting closer by going on an alternate ring or stay close on one spinning the same way.