# Arena strategy on Tron bikes on the interior of a sphere?

Tags: combat, strategy, fight

A group of humans have been transported to an alien arena, where they are forced to duel in many different arenas(I've asked about one of them [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/181458/fighting-techniques-in-an-arena-of-rings-rotating-in-alternating-directions)). This time, the characters have advanced from hand to hand combat to a sort of Tron bike. They drag behind them a field generator, which draws lines behind it that disappear after about fifteen seconds(higher difficulty may remain longer, up to a minute). Colliding with these lines caused the bike to crash, and most times the rider to die. In the event that the rider does not die, they have a small pistol they can try to use to regain a bike and a fighting chance. This is rare, so it should no affect the main strategy. The small pistol is also available while riding, but I would assume that guns on moving vehicles are a distraction and could cause a crash.

The arena is a sphere, with the bikes on the interior. In the center is a small floating orb, which creates strong gravitational field just above where the riders are. This field DOES NOT affect the riders, even if thrown up into it, only the small pistol shots. Using this field, trick shots can take out almost anyone anywhere with enough practice. But, if your not careful, you could shoot yourself. The pistols are basically an insta-kill if they hit a human, and fire the same fields as the generators which remain for ten seconds(again, higher difficulty may remain longer, up to twenty seconds). Colliding with these lines on a bike will most likely result in a crash. Assume the pistol has infinite ammunition.

Please note-

- the bikes do not make the lines, the generator dragged behind does, which can swing out in tight turns and be used as a weapon
- there is no cover from bikes or pistol shots
- everyone can see everyone, they just have to look in the right direction
- regardless of where you are, gravity makes it feel like you are still on the bottom
- it is flat inside(well, as flat as it can be in a sphere), so no trick jumps or flips or whatever
- only gamemode is deathmatch or team deathmatch, with anywhere between 2 and 12 players at once
- alien tech allows for severe acceleration and deceleration without popping your eyes out, or even really feeling it at all

Bike speed and sphere size has not been set in stone yet, but I guess we can say up to 80 mph for the bikes max, and then the sphere is...big?

Comment: You are not giving any info on the size of the sphere and on the velocity of the bikes. These info greatly affect the game strategy.

Comment: Also you first tell us to ignore the pistols strategy-wise, then go on about them for an entire paragraph. Why do we care about the pistols?

Comment: @fgysinreinstateMonica, because they are there. someone might come up with a good idea with them.

Comment: Does the field act as a solid object (blocking the dismounted riders too, and the crash is because it's a wall), or as a non-solid field which affects the bike's engine?   In other words: if I were to perform a leaning turn, so that the field was *diagonal* instead of *vertical*, could it be used as a ramp?  Also - if you fire a gun forward while riding a bike, does that mean you immediately impale the gun on the field it's just fired?

Comment: What's your question? Seeking a strategy is story not world building.

Comment: @puppetsock I tend to disagree. It appears to me that the OP is asking about the general *process* of finding a valid strategy given these conditions. That being said, I could be wrong; let the All Powerful Mods decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is difficult without knowing the:

Size of the bikes

Speed/acceleration of the bikes

Size of the sphere

Do the lines of death affect dismounted humans? (eg. can someone get off their bike and run around shooting people, ignoring the lines of death?)

What happens if the bikes ram each other?

If you hit a line and die, will your generator still keep working?

What about crashed bikes?

Can you detach a generator with a good shot?

Can you hit your own lines?

Does the side of a line explode bikes: ------  <-bike travels left, and hits the edge of the line, does it die?

However, I'l still answer, and assume everyone has the same velocity and won't randomly crash/fall off their bikes, and also assume your own lines are harmless.

A good strategy would just to sit still/move erratically in a small area and shoot people. You can't be hurt by other people's lines, and since it's hard to shoot while driving, your sitting still doesn't really make you a target. If anyone gets close, quickly cut them off.

Another strategy would to be spinning around in a circle. Nobody can cut you off due to your generator swinging out and creating a "forcefield" with larger radius than your movement radius. However, you can't really attack, and you can still get shot.

A third strategy is to bait people into chasing you, then laugh as they run into the edge of the line you leave behind. Alternatively, you can whip around and encircle them, hoping their momentum will fling them into your trail.

A fourth strategy is to dismount, set your bike to drive by itself, and run around and shoot at the ground, placing "traps" that take out opponents.

The last strategy, in team mode, is to ride in a circle with a few teammates, dividing the field, while the rest of your team huts down enemies in one half, while the other half, with more enemies, has only one or two guys playing defensively, trying to cut off opponents.

Edit: as Willis said, this will likely turn into a firefight anyway, since moving raises the issue of running into a line.

Answer (score 0):

1. Park bike.  Lean it against line generator.  You might turn line generator on its side.
2. Shelter beneath the 2 machines.
3. Make use of infinite ammo and start shooting.  Your opponents will also be hiding under their machines so it will take a while for the match to be over.
4. Play loud rocking music so spectators don't get bored.

Answer (score 0):

As you describe it the pistols are the most likely way to win. They have all of the advantages of the bikes without the disadvantages - in that they fire a lasting line with directional aiming rather than having to follow the path of your bike.

I'd aim to get ahead of my opponent and then fire the pistol left or right depending on which side they were on. No need to aim and they have to continually dodge the resulting fields. If they pull in behind you, they've lost as you can simply fire in a straight line backwards.

You might struggle against a very skilled driver but, given that this is a fatal sport, how many people are likely to get that much practice in?